# Angular2 ExpressJs - audio mp3 upload to the server (audio mp3 less than 16MB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, middleware

I'm about to start a project that will involve the user uploading audioMP3 files less than 16MB, which is less than the maximum file size for mongoDB. I have been searching but with no luck on how to implement this in the server side to recieve the mp3 file, save it to the DB and retrieve in the client. Any one done something similar or got any idea how to implement this specially the node express side.

Comment: You don't store files in database. Store it in FS and link location in database. Or better for starters use amazon s3 or something to store the files...

Comment: Or you can also use hadoop FileSystem for store the contents, but judging from your problem that might be a very tough road

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Thank you, what I finally did was to load the files in AWS and store their url MongoDB, later requested for them in my application and load them in the browser